# iOS: Creating a form application in Swift

Tags: ios, class

I am starting my first application in Swift after spending a bit of time using objective c. I would like to create a registration application. Here are the features I have decided that it needs.

- The application will have a default set of questions such as what is your name, email, etc.
- The application will give users ability to delete and add new questions.
- The application will give users ability to make questions required
- The application will allow you to save form templates that you have created to use at a later time.

I'm struggling to layout my program in the correct way and write good code. Should I create a class for each one of these features and then implement the proper methods? Should it look something like this?

```
class defaultQuestions {
     // create text labels
     // create text fields
}

class modifyQuestions {
     // methods for creating questions
     // methods for deleting questions
     // methods for making questions required
}

class saveForm {
     // method for saving form template
}

// code for implementing table view

// action (button) for adding question
// action (button) deleting question
// action (button) saving form as template
```

If you have any suggestions for my planned implementation let me know. I haven't quite fleshed out how I will write each class yet, I'm just more interested in getting an overall layout for the code.

Comment: yeah, that looks neat. You can also use "extension" for one class by by adding specific functions in it.

Comment: No, that is right at all. A class should represent an object such as a question. The methods/functions of the class act on that object. You should have a Question class with methods that act on the question instances.

Comment: BTW - your question has nothing to do with Swift. You are asking about general object oriented design principles.

Comment: So all I need is a questions class and it'll implement methods for modifying the questions? Sorry about that.. I made the tags at the beginning thinking I might ask something about swift. I'll edit.

Comment: You'll obviously have a lot more than just the one class. But the ones you propose don't make much sense.

Comment: Okay. I appreciate your tips. I'm not sure how saving a form template would work just yet, but would a template be considered an object?